Can women testify in crimes other than Hudood and Qisas?
Is it true that women cant testify for crimes unless the man is testifying alongside them? Or that the criminal isnt punished if the witnesses were women? I already know a womans testimony isnt accepted for hudud or qisas, but what about other punishments?

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

I'd like to point at the following relevant questions: Are there cases where only male witnesses are allowed?, Can 4 women be witnesses...? and Why isn't a woman's testimony accepted in had punishments?

It depends on the nature of the crime and the school of thought.
The testimony of women is not acceptable in Hudood and Qisas, see Why isn't a women’s testimony accept in Hadd punishments?.
As for other crimes they fall under Ta'zeer, and the punishments can be either:

Physical, such as flogging or imprisonment. These apply in violations against Allah (such as kissing a woman who is not lawful to you) and at times also in violations against the people (such as insulting a person).

Monetary, such as being held financially liable for damages. These apply to violations against the people where they are compensated for damages to their person or property.


The testimony of women is accepted if the crime is against a person and the punishment is monetary. The reason is that the testimony of women is acceptable in financial liabilities as per the Quran:

إذا تداينتم بدين ... واستشهدوا شهيدين من رجالكم فإن لم يكونا رجلين فرجل وامرأتان ممن ترضون من الشهداء أن تضل إحداهما فتذكر إحداهما الأخرى
When you contract a debt ... bring to witness two witnesses from among your men. And if there are not two men [available], then a man and two women from those whom you accept as witnesses - so that if one of the women errs, then the other can remind her.
— Quran 2:282

According to the majority the requirement is that there must be at least one male and two female witnesses. Women alone will not be sufficient as witnesses (even if they are four in number) as per the apparent wording of the verse.
If the punishment is physical then the view of the Shafi'is, Hanbalis and one view of the Hanafis is that the testimony of women is not acceptable, rather the witnesses must be two males as the case is analogous to Hudood and Qisas. The Hanafis also have a second view in their madhab according to which if the matter is regarding the rights of the people then one male and two females can give testimony on that case.
Ref: Radd al-Muhtaar and Al-Mughni
